# Select on Azure Table Storage taking too long to return

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have an application in .Net Core that collects the properties of files from several servers here in the company, all this data is stored in two tables of Azure Table Storage. One for files on Linux servers and one for files on Windows servers. So far so good, the insertion part is even quick.

The problem is that I insert about 375k of rows per day in the table and every 6 months I have to extract all this data for analysis.

That's where the problem lives, I have to extract 375k x 180 = 67kk of lines in one go.

How to do this in a "quick" way? I left my application running for 3 days and was unable to get a return. I tested it on a table with 590k of rows and it returned in 34 seconds, however in the bigger table it never reaches the end.

Many will ask me. "Why Azure Table?" So, this is not my thing, I work with software testing, at the time of creating this application, I asked for help from a software architect and after several conversations, he told me to use this technology (which is not serving me)

I'm already starting to change the code to work with Cosmos DB, but for this month's collection, I still need to use Table Storage.

Does anyone know if there is a better way to collect than the one below?

```
 public List<LogFileLinux> GetAllAsyncLin(DateTime dataMinima)
        {
            return _table.CreateQuery<LogFileLinux>().Where(x => x.Modified > dataMinima).ToList();
        }
```

another form that I was using is this, but it seems to me that it takes the same time.

```
 public async Task<List<T>> GetAllAsync(string query = "")
        {
            List<T> arquivos = new List<T>();
            
            TableQuery<T> partitionScanQuery = new TableQuery<T>().Where(query);
            TableContinuationToken token = null;
            // Page through the results
            do
            {
                TableQuerySegment<T> segment = await _table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(partitionScanQuery, token);
                token = segment.ContinuationToken;
                arquivos.AddRange(segment);
            } while (token != null);

            return arquivos;
        }
```

In this call I spend a minimum date to filter the amount of files.

Comment: Translated using Google Translate :).

Comment: the problem seems to be related to your row key / partition key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to do this in a "quick" way?

Make use of Partition keys. Even more faster? Make combined use of `Partition` and `Row` Keys. As you know,

> *Tables are divided into partitions. Every entity stored in a partition shares the same partition key and has a unique row key to identify it within that partition.*

If you run a `table scan` (without making use of these keys), there is no doubt why there is an impact in performance. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-for-query) on design for querying.